# Django: Can the value of ForeignKey be None?

Tags: python, database, django, foreign-keys

I have a model called `SimplePage` in which I have this line:

```
category = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='items',
                             blank=True, null=True)
```

I assumed this will allow me to have SimplePage instances that do not have a Category.

But for some reason, when I try to create a SimplePage in the Admin with no Category, I get:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/sitehelpers/simplepage/add/
sitehelpers_simplepage.category_id may not be NULL
```

What is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it possibly be that you added the `null=True` attribute after doing the `syncdb` for that model? Django won't change database tables, only create them. Check in your database if `NULL` is allowed for that column and change it manually.

**Edit**: starting with Django 1.7, this answer and the comments are not really valid anymore, since Django gained a fully featured [migration framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/).

Comment: Remember kids: Django will only CREATE tables or columns if they don't exist. It will never ALTER a table for you. Any table changes necessary to reflect changes to models will have to be done manually by you!

Comment: ...or you can start using third-party schema migration assistant, like South.

Comment: I actually ran syncdb and it didn't help. What worked was deleting the db and then doing syncdb.

Comment: @cool-RR, synack's comment about syncdb creating but not modifying tables is what bit you.

Comment: I expected syncdb to give a warning about this.

Comment: this is clearly documented behavior: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb. If you don't bother to read the documentation, you're bound to run into a wall once in a while.

Comment: Does it say there that syncdb will not give a warning?